# jQuery mobile page doesn't take full width/zoom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi guys I searched a lot but I can't find a solution to my problem, I'm using jQuery mobile and I have an element which has `data-role="page" and data-url="link"`

Now my problem is that my element doesn't take the full width of the screen, like the user has zoom in to the max,that's what I want.I also set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` but with no luck :(

Please guys give me a solution.

//LE

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $var1 = query_posts('post_type=Home Pages&meta_key=select_column_column&meta_value=Left');?>
 <?php if (have_posts($var1)) : ?>
     <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php $color = get_post_meta($post->ID,'select_color_color',true); ?>
                <article data-role="page" data-transition="slide">
                    <div class="sprite top-<?=$color?>"></div>
                    <div class="txt <?=$color?> clearfix">
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                          <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-image'); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sprite bottom-<?=$color?>"></div>
                </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>


  $('article').bind("swipeleft", function(){
    var nextpage = $(this).next('article[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
      $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide",
    reverse: false}, true, true);
    }
    $('article').unbind('swipeleft', nextpage);
  });

  $('article').bind("swiperight", function(){
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('article[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
    $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
    reverse: true}, false, true);
    }
    $('article').unbind('swiperight', prevpage);
  });
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Done! Sir here you go!

Comment: Please post rendered html markup instead of php code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your viewport tag in the document head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This should set a definitive width and prevent zooming in and out, allowing you to grab a fixed width in jQuery.

Comment: In your code at the top, you didn't have `initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1` - these are the magic words that work for me...

You can then set the width (in css) of your element to 100%...

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot it looks like my main image has 224px so in order to take the whole space/width it needs to be 400px+

Comment: If this has resolved your problem, please accept your answer which will prevent it from being listed as unanswered.

Comment: Could also make the width of the image 100%, adding max-width and min-width to constrain it from being overly scaled or shrunk.